# Recursively building up cons lists

Tags: recursion, clojure, tail-recursion, cons

I'm writing a program that uses classical cons pairs a la Common Lisp, Scheme, et al.

```
(deftype Cons [car cdr]
  clojure.lang.ISeq
    (first [c] (.car c))
    (more [c] (.cdr c))
```

I create lists by chaining cons cells, e.g. `(Cons. a (Cons. b nil))` for the list containing `a` and `b`. I wrote a function to convert a Clojure collection into a cons list:

```
(defn conslist [xs]
  (if (empty? xs)
      nil
      (Cons. (first xs) (conslist (rest xs)))))
```

This works but will overflow if `xs` is too big. `recur` doesn't work because the recursive call isn't in a tail position. Using `loop` with an accumulator wouldn't work, because `cons` only puts stuff at the front, when each recurse gives you the *next* item, and I can't use `conj`.

What can I do?

Edit: In the end, it turns out if you get this working, Clojure fundamentally isn't designed to support cons pairs (you can't set the tail to a non-seq). I ended up just creating a custom data structure and car/cdr functions.

Comment: I think without resorting to some optimisation workarounds you can use `loop` and then `revert` its result before returning it.

Comment: could you include a sample call to `Cons.` that works, along with it's output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lazy-seq` is your friend here. It takes a body that evaluates to an ISeq, but the body will not be evaluated until the result of `lazy-seq` is invoked.

```
(defn conslist [xs]
  (if (empty? xs)
      nil
      (lazy-seq (Cons. (first xs) (conslist (rest xs))))))
```

Comment: When I try to run this solution I get java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: @AlanThompson I shortened the definition of `Cons` for my post. You need to implement `empty`.

Comment: Using something as sophisticated as lazy-seq seems to defeat the purpose of illustrating "classic cons pairs".

Answer (score 2):

as usual, i would propose the simplest loop/recur:

```
(defn conslist [xs]
  (loop [xs (reverse xs) res nil]
    (if (empty? xs)
      res
      (recur (rest xs) (Cons. (first xs) res)))))
```

Comment: This works, but he specifically asked for a lazy version. Otherwise, I would just use `reduce` or something